# How to convert an ipython notebook to html with collapsed output (and/or input)

Tags: javascript, python, html, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I have an `ipython notebook` I'd like to share with colleagues who may not have ipython installed.

So I converted it to html with :

```
ipython nbconvert my_notebook.ipynb
```

But my problem is that I have very long outputs which make the reading difficult, and I'd like to know whether it's possible to have the collapse or scroll option of the notebook viewer on the html version.

**Basically, I'd like this : [output example](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/2/_images/ipy_013_notebook_long_out.png)**
[image]

But in the html version. Is this even possible ?

Thanks for helping !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found what I wanted thanks to that [blog](https://damianavila.github.io/blog/posts/mimic-the-ipython-notebook-cell-execution.html) which does exactly what I wanted.

I modified it a bit to make it work with ipython 2.1 [edit: works aslo with Jupyter], and mixed the input and output hidding tricks.

## What it does:

When opening the html file, all input will be shown and output hidden. By clicking on the input field it will show the output field. And once you have both fields, you can hide one by clicking the other.

edit: It now hides long input, and about 1 line is always shown (by defa. You can show everything by clicking on the input number. This is convenient when you don't have output (like a definition of a long function you'd like to hide in your HTML doc)

You need to add a template while doing nbconvert :

```
ipython nbconvert --template toggle my_notebook.ipynb
```

where toggle is a file containing :

```
{%- extends 'full.tpl' -%}

{% block output_group %}
<div class="output_hidden">
{{ super() }}
</div>
{% endblock output_group %}

{% block input_group -%}
<div class="input_hidden">
{{ super() }}
</div>
{% endblock input_group %}

{%- block input -%}
<div class="in_container">
<div class="in_hidden">
{{ super() }}
<div class="gradient">
</div>
</div>
</div>
{%- endblock input -%}


{%- block header -%}
{{ super() }}

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
div.output_wrapper {
  margin-top: 0px;
}
.output_hidden {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 5px;
}
.in_hidden {
   width: 100%;
   overflow: hidden;
   position: relative;
}

.in_container {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: 20px;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.gradient {
    width:100%;
    height:3px;  
    background:#eeeeee;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0;
    display: none;
    opacity: 0.4;
    border-bottom: 2px dashed #000;
}
div.input_prompt {
    color: #178CE3;
    font-weight: bold;
}
div.output_prompt {
    color: rgba(249, 33, 33, 1);
    font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".output_hidden").click(function(){
      $(this).prev('.input_hidden').slideToggle();
  });
  $(".input_hidden").click(function(){
      $(this).next('.output_hidden').slideToggle();
  });
var slideHeight = 25;
$(".in_container").each(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $in_hidden = $this.children(".in_hidden");
    var defHeight = $in_hidden.height();
    if (defHeight >= 61) {
        var $prompt = $this.prev(".input_prompt");
        var $gradient = $in_hidden.children(".gradient");
        $in_hidden.css("height", slideHeight + "px");
        $gradient.css("display", "block");
        $prompt.click(function () {
            var curHeight = $in_hidden.height();
            if (curHeight == slideHeight) {
                $in_hidden.animate({
                    height: defHeight
                }, "normal");
                $gradient.fadeOut();
            } 
            else {
                $in_hidden.animate({
                    height: slideHeight
                }, "normal");
                $gradient.fadeIn();
            }
            return false;
        });
    }
});
});

</script>
{%- endblock header -%}
```

Basically, you can inject whatever javascript and css you want to customize your notebook at will!

Have fun !

Comment: link changed to http://damianavila.github.io/blog/posts/mimic-the-ipython-notebook-cell-execution.html

Answer (score 0):

Ipython 2.0 now includes save to HTML directly within the notebook.

The scrolling bars were automatically created with lines > 100 in an older version. [Docs](http://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/whatsnew/version0.13.html) If they still show, your html output should also have the bars, no?

Comment: mmh I have Ipython 2.1, so maybe it's that, but auto-scroll seems to be disable on Firefox "The auto-folding of long outputs is disabled in Firefox due to bugs in its scrolling behavior. See PR #2047 for details." (from your link)

Comment: Try 3.0, saving in Chrome?

Comment: 3.0 is still in dev, and I found a solution. Thanks

Comment: I made an error -- 2.0 includes download to html from the notebook. You seem set though.

Comment: Note that I have a horizontal scrolling behavior for large tables for instance (without any javascript from me)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code to convert your notebook into HTML with code as collapsed.

```
from IPython.display import HTML

HTML('''<script>
code_show=true; 
function code_toggle() {
 if (code_show){
 $('div.input').hide();
 } else {
 $('div.input').show();
 }
 code_show = !code_show
} 
$( document ).ready(code_toggle);
</script>
<form action="javascript:code_toggle()"><input type="submit" value="Click here to toggle on/off the raw code."></form>''')
```