# Insert figure into iPython markdown cell

Tags: python, ipython, markdown, jupyter-notebook

In iPython I create an image in one cell using the Pandas plot function. In a different markdown cell in the same notebook I would like to add this figure inline.

Is it possible to reference notebook internal figures in a markdown cell without saving them to disk?

Answer (score 2):

Edit : it's in the same notebook !

Yes you can, but not in the markdown cell (as far as I know).

Just save your figure in a figure object (if not already done by `fig = plt.figure()` )

```
plt.plot(...)
fig = plt.gcf()
```

And then call `fig` wherever in the notebook. To get rid of the input cell after html conversion, see below.

---

If between 2 distinct notebooks (but also work in the same notebook)

The closest I can get to your request is to use the base64 address of the image :

So far it seems that markdown doesn't deal well with this, but you can put the following in a `%%html` magic cell.

```
%%html
<img alt="Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG ... hEJRU5ErkJggg==" />
```

With

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG ... hEJRU5ErkJggg==
```

being your image in base64. You can get this address just by right clicking on the image in the other notebook and select "copy image address" (if it's inline image). Otherwise you can use image to base64 converter.

Here you'll still get the input cell visible, but if you eventually convert your notebook in html, you'll be able to hide the input cells with some Javascript. ([See here for how to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24062013/how-to-convert-an-ipython-notebook-to-html-with-collapsed-output-and-or-input), disclaimer: it's my answer (to my question)).

At the end, you'll be able to hide the `%%html`magic cell while keeping the image.

Hope this helps

Comment: You can also `savefig(...)` and `![myfig](file/path-to-myfig.png)` in md cell.

Comment: yes but the OP asked without saving the image to disk !

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily if you keep the [Axes](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes) instance when creating the figure:

```py
t = arange(0,6,0.01)
x = sin(t)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.plot(t,x)
```

If you're using pandas plotting functions, first create the axes as before and then pass the instance to the pandas plotting function as argument: `pandas.DataFrame.plot(ax=ax)`. An example:

```py
from pandas import Series, date_range
ts = Series(randn(1000), index=date_range('1/1/2000', periods=1000))
ts = ts.cumsum()

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ts.plot(ax=ax)
```

Then you can reuse the same figure in another cell:

```py
display(ax.get_figure())
```

Comment: Great. `display` allows the reuse of an existing `axes`.

Answer (score 1):

The matplotlib magic line might do what you want:

```
%matplotlib inline
```

It will go into an output cell.